# Query.FilterOperator for different roles

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am new to programming world, and i love it.

I have some problem on Query.Filter Operator by different roles.

- Admin - Admin can view all leave history
- Supervisor - Supervisor can view own and all employee under he/she
- Employee - Employee only able to view own leave history

From the testing i has done. Admin and Employee is working fine and the problem I has faced is Supervisor, Supervisor able to view employee under he/she but **unable to view own leave history**.

here are part of the code, appreciate anyone can help me. Thank you

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    log.debug(ViewHistory.class);
    DataTableModel dataTableModel = DataTablesUtility.getParam(request);
    String regionSelected = request.getParameter("cri_region");
    String sEcho = dataTableModel.sEcho;
    int iTotalRecords = 0; // total number of records (unfiltered)
    int iTotalDisplayRecords = 0; //value will be set when code filters companies by keyword
    JsonArray data = new JsonArray(); //data that will be shown in the table

    String emailAddress = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("emailAdd");
    Boolean isAdmin = false;
    Boolean isSupervisor = false;

    AdministratorService as = new AdministratorService();
    for(Administrator admin : as.getAdministrators()){
        if(admin.getEmailAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(emailAddress)){
            isAdmin = true;
        }
    }

    SupervisorService ss = new SupervisorService();
    for(Supervisor s : ss.getSupervisors()){
        if(s.getEmailAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(emailAddress)){
            isSupervisor = true;
        }
    }

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Query q = new Query(History.class.getSimpleName());
            // only admin can view all leave history
            if(!isAdmin && !isSupervisor){
                Filter emailFilter = new FilterPredicate("emailAdd",
                        FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                        emailAddress);
                Filter regionFilter = new FilterPredicate("region",
                        FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                        StringUtils.defaultString(regionSelected, "Singapore"));
                Filter filter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(emailFilter, regionFilter);
                q.setFilter(filter);
            }
            else if(!isAdmin && isSupervisor){
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService();
                for(Employee emp : es.getEmployees()){
                    if(emailAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(emp.getSupervisor())){
                        list.add(emp.getEmailAddress());
                    }
                }

                // if some one under this supervisor
                if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){
                    Filter filter = new FilterPredicate("emailAdd",
                            FilterOperator.IN,
                            list);
                    q.setFilter(filter);
                }
                else{
                    // if not one under this supervisor , put update it self to avoid illegal argument
                    Filter filter = new FilterPredicate("emailAdd",
                            FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                            emailAddress);
                    q.setFilter(filter);
                }

            }

    List<History> historyList = new LinkedList<History>();
    List<History> entityList = new LinkedList<History>();
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated suggestion.

If currently for a supervisor you are able to correctly get the list of all employees who have him as the supervisor, then just add the supervisor's email also to the list which you will be using as a filter for querying leave history. So after finding the list of  employee emails, also add:

```
list.add(emailAddress);  //since emailAddress will be the email of the supervisor
```

Comment: Dear Tony, thanks for your suggestion, i has tested it, now it become Supervisor only able to view own leave history but not employee under he/she

Comment: can you please check your test case, whether you are testing a case where there is no one under the supervisor